# Допустимо ли авторское тире для отделения придаточного?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение, авторская-пунктуация

*Это когда не нужно жить в офисе: обработка заказов удалённо, переговоры в чатах Telegram, отчётность в общих документах Google Docs, [—] так что работать можно из любой точки.*

Последнее придаточное следствия хотелось бы выделить из ряда предшествуюших назывных предложений и подчеркнуть его отнесённость к ним как к группе предыдущим назывным предложениям после двоеточия.

И ещё хочу уточнить: если придаточное следствия стоит после предложений, соединённых сочинительной или бессоюзной связью, то оно по смыслу относится только к последнему или ко всей группе предшествующих предикативных частей сложного предложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это когда не нужно жить в офисе: обработка заказов — удалённо, переговоры — в чатах Telegram, отчётность — в общих документах Google Docs, так что работать можно из любой точки.**

(Я поставила дополнительные тире, мне кажется, так текст понятнее).

Авторское тире может заменять запятую, это разрешается, а вот как дополнительный знак особо не приветствуется. В вашем же случае, как я думаю, **тире  вообще не нужно.**

**Здесь два смысловых блока,** разделенных двоеточием, а это сильный знак, обозначающий значительно увеличенную пояснительную паузу. Все предложения после двоеточия входят **во второй блок**: это три предложения с бессоюзной связью и четвертое предложение с союзом ТАК ЧТО, которое обозначает их общее следствие и является замыкающим по отношению к ним.

Примерно так строятся **сложные предложения с различными видами связи,** материал на эту тему есть в ПАС. § 132. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136